# Why arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ar says "invalid option -- 'g'" whereas this option doesn't appear in the args list of the command line?

Tags: makefile, augmented-reality, autotools, automake

I am using bitbake building command "bitbake -v update-engine-titan-c" and here are the logs :

```
[le944v7:latest] /LE944V7/meta-titan bitbake -v update-engine-titan-c
.../...
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.40.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "ubuntu-18.04"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "le944v7"
DISTRO               = "poky-ivt-systemd"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "12.0.0"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm armv7ve vfp neon vfpv4 callconvention-hard cortexa7"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
.../...
    
make[2]: Entering directory '/LE944V7/meta-titan/build/artefacts/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/update-engine-titan-c/1.0-r0/build/src/wrapper'
rm -f libupdate_engine_titan_c_wrapper.a

arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ar cru libupdate_engine_titan_c_wrapper.a update_attempter_wrapper.o -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lcrypto -lcurl -llog -lssl -lprotobuf-lite -lpthread -lbz2 -lgflags -lbase -lchrome -lbrillo -lbrillo_stream -levent -lbspatch -lfstab -lbootctrl -lxz -lpuffpatch -lbrotli 

arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ar: invalid option -- 'g'
Usage: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ar [emulation options] [-]{dmpqrstx}[abcDfilMNoOPsSTuvV] [--plugin <name>] [member-name] [count] archive-file file...
       arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ar -M [<mri-script]
 commands:
  d            - delete file(s) from the archive
  m[ab]        - move file(s) in the archive
  p            - print file(s) found in the archive
  q[f]         - quick append file(s) to the archive
  r[ab][f][u]  - replace existing or insert new file(s) into the archive
  s            - act as ranlib
  t[O][v]      - display contents of the archive
  x[o]         - extract file(s) from the archive
 command specific modifiers:
  [a]          - put file(s) after [member-name]
  [b]          - put file(s) before [member-name] (same as [i])
  [D]          - use zero for timestamps and uids/gids (default)
  [U]          - use actual timestamps and uids/gids
  [N]          - use instance [count] of name
  [f]          - truncate inserted file names
  [P]          - use full path names when matching
  [o]          - preserve original dates
  [O]          - display offsets of files in the archive
  [u]          - only replace files that are newer than current archive contents
 generic modifiers:
  [c]          - do not warn if the library had to be created
  [s]          - create an archive index (cf. ranlib)
  [S]          - do not build a symbol table
  [T]          - make a thin archive
  [v]          - be verbose
  [V]          - display the version number
  @<file>      - read options from <file>
  --target=BFDNAME - specify the target object format as BFDNAME
 optional:
  --plugin <p> - load the specified plugin
 emulation options: 
  No emulation specific options
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ar: supported targets: elf32-littlearm elf32-littlearm-fdpic elf32-bigarm elf32-bigarm-fdpic elf32-little elf32-big plugin srec symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary ihex
```

I don't understand why arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ar says "invalid option -- 'g'" whereas this option doesn't appear in arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ar args list in the command line (see log) ?

Comment: I suspect the `-lgio-2.0` option is being treated as multiple `-l -g -i...` options, hence the error message.  What are `-lgio-2.0` etc. supposed to do within the context of an `ar` command line?

Comment: You are right, this option isn't normal. The error message is linked to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `ar` doesn't take `-lgio-2.0` arguments. I think you're supposed to put the path to the `libgio-2.0.so` file directly on the command line, not via a `-l` argument.

(In the `ar` manpage it says the `-l` argument is accepted but ignored, so I suspect G.M. is correct in the comment in saying that `-lgio-2.0` is where the `-g` comes from)

Comment: Actually, I removed var xxx_LIBADD from Makefile.am which was responsible for adding those options and my problem disappeared. I don't need this var actually (it was inherited from another project)

Answer (score 0):

An extension to @ptomato's answer is that `ar` will interpret anything starting with a `-` as a bunch of short-letter options coming after each other, so while `-l` is a valid short-letter option in `ar`, other letters coming after it might not be and that's how it triggers an "unknown option" error.

It's actually even worse if all the letters passed are miraculously valid because then `ar` will be running in an undefined way and make more subtle errors down the road.

For example, passing `-lm` to `ar` (this can happen if you specify it in your automake `*_LIBADD` variables, for example) might make you think that you are linking to the math library but it will actually tell `ar` to *move* files around in the static lib (`-m` option).